# Get value from json string using key's value

Tags: javascript

Hi I have a json string

```
"{"data":[{"Id":14,"ConfigName":"Online Hrs","ConfigValue":"00:01-23:59"},{"Id":15,"ConfigName":"Offline Days","ConfigValue":"Sunday"},{"Id":0,"ConfigName":"CurrentTime","ConfigValue":"11:3"}]}"
```

I want to check `ConfigValue` of `ConfigName` "CurrentTime".
Currently I am accessing it by below code

```
var d = JSON.parse(data).data;
d[2].ConfigValue
```

but sometimes the json string will be

```
"{"data":[{"Id":14,"ConfigName":"Online Hrs","ConfigValue":"00:01-23:59"},{"Id":0,"ConfigName":"CurrentTime","ConfigValue":"11:3"}]}"
```

according to above string now if i want to access "CurrentTime"

I will have to write below code

```
 var d = JSON.parse(data).data;
    d[1].ConfigValue
```

So can anyone tell how to access it? Because the array may change anytime so I cannot hardcode the array index like that.

Comment: Please use the search: [`[javascript] find object array`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+find+object+array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a loop and check the value of `ConfigName`. Below is the code

```js
var data = '{"data":[{"Id":14,"ConfigName":"Online Hrs","ConfigValue":"00:01-23:59"},{"Id":15,"ConfigName":"Offline Days","ConfigValue":"Sunday"},{"Id":0,"ConfigName":"CurrentTime","ConfigValue":"11:3"}]}';
var d = JSON.parse(data).data;

for(var i=0; i<d.length; i++)
{
if(d[i].ConfigName === 'CurrentTime')
  {
   alert(d[i].ConfigValue); //Do stuff with the value.
  }
}
```

Comment: Relying on the fact the value only contains a single `:` is so hacky. Why not just look for the object where `ConfigName === 'CurrentTime'` ?

Comment: @FelixKling yes you are right. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

You have same quotes inside and outside string without escaping. But maybe it takes place only in question texts.

In this case You need to check every item like this:

```
 for (var i in d) {
   if (d[i].Id == 0) {
       alert(d[i].ConfigName);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
var k = {"data":[{"Id":14,"ConfigName":"Online Hrs","ConfigValue":"00:01-23:59"},{"Id":15,"ConfigName":"Offline Days","ConfigValue":"Sunday"},{"Id":0,"ConfigName":"CurrentTime","ConfigValue":"11:3"}]}
    
    var result = $(jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(k))).each(function() {  
         var configName = this.ConfigName;
         var configValue = this.ConfigValue;
         
    });
 console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why do you use jQuery here? And why do you convert the object to JSON just to parse it again? Seems more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to find the object in the array with "ConfigValue" equal to "CurrentTime". Once you have this object, you can simply access its "CongigValue" property.

```js
var json1 = {"data":
             [
               {"Id":14,"ConfigName":"Online Hrs","ConfigValue":"00:01-23:59"},{"Id":15,"ConfigName":"Offline Days","ConfigValue":"Sunday"},{"Id":0,"ConfigName":"CurrentTime","ConfigValue":"11:3"}
             ]
            };

var json2 = {"data":
             [
               {"Id":14,"ConfigName":"Online Hrs","ConfigValue":"00:01-23:59"},{"Id":0,"ConfigName":"CurrentTime","ConfigValue":"11:3"}
             ]
            };


var currentTime = findCurrentTime( json1 );
console.log( "currentTime: " + currentTime );

var currentTime = findCurrentTime( json2 );
console.log( "currentTime: " + currentTime );



function findCurrentTime( jsonObj )
{
  var filteredArray = jsonObj.data.filter(function(element){
     return element.ConfigName === "CurrentTime";
  });//filter()

  if( filteredArray.length > 0 )
    return filteredArray[0].ConfigValue;
  
  return false;
}//findCurrentTime()
```